# ¿Puedo instalar paquetes de node.js sin conexión a internet?

Tags: nodejs, npm

Antes que nada quiero aclarar que soy de Cuba y **aquí el internet es súper caro, costando $1 por hora** y por eso formulo esta pregunta. Sé que normalmente los paquetes de node se instalan muy fácil por sus respectivos comandos y todo funciona muy bien y genial pero hay que tener conexión a internet.

Me gustaría saber, por favor, si alguien sabe como descargar los paquetes de node para poder instalarlos sin conexión a internet en mi computadora Cabe destacar que la computadora en la que escribo no es mi PC personal por lo que necesito poder descargarlos para más adelante y instalarlos sin conexión a internet. Estoy usando un proxy para la conexión a internet.

**Agradecería muchísimo si alguien me ayuda y me explica paso a paso como hacer esto posible, no se imaginan cuanto se los agradecería. Muchas gracias de antemano.**

Comment: puedes, si puedes crearte un git server e instalarte todas las librerias que necesites en tu server, una vez eso , haces un juego con el archivo host para que te descargue de tu git server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes que descargar los módulos **al menos una vez** y depende de que módulo estas tratando (por ejemplo que requieran compilación como `node-sass`).

Si el módulo está cacheado y no es muy antiguo puedes hacer la instalación offline completa. Por ejemplo si creas una aplicación de express podrías instalar sus dependencias a continuación estando desconectado porque todos los módulos que requiere y sus dependencias están almacenados en la caché. Debes tener en cuenta que esto no es 100% seguro ya que:

> La caché npm es estrictamente una caché: no se debe contar con ella como un modo de almacenamiento persistente y seguro de paquetes. npm no hace ninguna garantía que una información almacenada previamente va a estar disponible y automáticamente elimina contenido corrupto. La garantía principal es que si se encuentran los datos estos serán idénticos a como se descargaron.

Para situaciones como esta es muy buena idea crear o instalar los módulos que usas a menudo aunque no los vayas a utilizar para que la caché se mantenga fresca. Si te mueves de estación de trabajo deberías llevarte las [carpetas](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#cache) `npm` y `npm-cache` que se encuentran en `~\AppData\Roaming\` si estuvieras trabajando en Windows y `~/.npm` en Linux. Si no se encuentran en esa ruta puedes ejecutar el comando  `npm config ls -l` este te arrojara la configuración general y dentro de ella donde guarda la cache que se mostrara algo como `cache = la_ruta_de_tu_cache`

---

La alternativa puede ser **montar un servidor y clonar todo el repo npm** pero esto podría ser más problemático aún ya que el repo es enorme y terminará costándote mucho más descargarlo y mantenerlo que instalar un proyecto en particular que sólo requiere que la instalación se efectúe una sola vez. Podrías hablar con algún amigo que venga del extranjero para que te lo descargue allá y te lo facilite pero aún así es una solución temporal ya que npm actualiza su contenido constantemente y tus proyectos de quedarán desactualizados rápidamente.

Cómo mejor y última opción puedes usar un **administrador de repositorios** como [artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) que se integra con npm y te mantiene los módulos de una manera más persistente *a medida que los vas descargando* lo cual permite que el costo de acceso a internet sea mínimo pero desde luego tienes que descargar los paquetes al menos una vez. Hay [un video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wYf9unk_Uw) en la propia página que te explica como configurarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Apróximadamente cuánto pesaría todo el repositorio de npm y donde podría bajarlo completo? Tampoco se como montar ese servidor, disculpe la ignorancia pero soy nuevo en esto. Me interesa el hecho de que se mantengan todas las dependencias sin que se borren de la cache durante un buen tiempo para poder trabajar offline. Cuál de todas estas vías sería la más fácil y que asegure que funcionen sin error ni complicación los módulos de npm según su opinión?

Comment: El tamaño aumenta con el tiempo pero debería ser más de 50Gb. Puedes encontrar una guía [aquí](http://www.remotecto.net/2013/06/20/how-to-create-an-npm-repository-mirror/). De nuevo, artifactory te funcionará mejor y será más barato. Si te sirvió la respuesta no te olvides de marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Creo que no optaré por artifactory porque al final cuesta dinero y necesito de una solución gratuita. Para ejemplificar mejor lo que necesito, por ejemplo, si yo quisiera instalar angular 8 o alguna otro repositorio más pequeño de npm por qué vía lo haría más fácil y sencillo y gratuito?

Comment: @C0D3BREAK3R Sólo pregunta por ahí en las empresas y es posible que alguien te pueda ayudar

Comment: No, no tengo nadie por aquí cerca que sepa del tema ni que tenga artifactory. Ya me las arreglare yo

Comment: @C0D3BREAK3R En Desoft se usa. Si clonas el repo `npm` se te quedará obsoleto en un mes y necesitarás ayuda del exterior para que te lo descarguen.

Comment: Pero es necesario actualizar el repo de npm todos los meses obligado?

Comment: @C0D3BREAK3R Ese es precisamente el problema. Existen muchísimos módulos de `npm` y eso se multiplica por las versiones que tiene cada módulo y cuando especificas versiones en el `package.json` si no encuentras la dependencia correcta la instalación no funciona o sea que si, se volverá obsoleto en muy poco tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

a mi me pasa exactamente lo mismo, soy de cuba, y al principio no sabía cómo hacerlo, pero es súper fácil.

Solo tienes que crearte una carpeta en su directorio, dónde vas a crear tu programa.
node_modules/
 Dentro de la carpeta, puedes poner los módulos, y después llamarlos de manera normal:
De esa manera lo podrás ejecutar.
Pero si aún así no funciona, deberás llamar al módulo, localmente poniendo la dirección del mismo despues de, require('./node_modules/ejemplo/Index.js)');
Si quieres usar express, tendrás que ponerle todos los módulos de manera local, y demás
Yo me tarde como 3 díaz en poder hacerlo todo