# ¿Cómo instalar express.js desde cuba si mi conexión es lenta?

Tags: express.js, descargar

Necesito instalar por consola `express.js` de `node.js` para experimentar pero me da el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://npmjs.org/express failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

No sé si se debe al `proxy` o a la lentitud de la conexión, yo descargo paquetes por consola en python descarga bien.

Gracias de antemano y si me pudieran ayudar se lo agradecería.
Otra cosa, serian tan amables de decirme cuánto pesa `express.js` en total para saber el aproximado de tiempo y datos que necesito para descargarlo.

Comment: Hola. Revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18419144/5587982).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Puedo instalar paquetes de node.js sin conexión a internet?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274255/puedo-instalar-paquetes-de-node-js-sin-conexi%c3%b3n-a-internet)